How to accommodate geotiff overlays a geometry/feature on the map
as shown in the below posted screen-shots, the one titled digit-area represents the geometry the user selected on the map.
for the one titled tiff-overlay it should represent the geotiff repective to the geometry the user selected when it overlays it. in other words, tiff-overlay is the overlay layer
over digit-area.
the problems now are:
1-as shown in tiff-overlay the area in gray refers to the geometry the user selected which is shown in digit-area, and the rest of the vision port/scope in
blacked-out, as shown in the screen-shot, in black. is it possible to remove the black region surrounds the tiff?i know it is a part of the tiff, but is there any way to eliminate it.
2-once the geometry the user selected gets overlayed with the geotiff, i can not neither zoom in or out. why is that happening and how to solve it please.
instance of GeoTIFF
geoTIFFSource = new GeoTIFF({
    wrapX: true,
    normalize: false,
    zoom: 1,
    extent: this.#mapInstance.getView().calculateExtent(this.#mapInstance.getSize()),
    sources: [
      {
        blob: res,
        overviews: ['https://openlayers.org/data/raster/no-overviews.tif.ovr'],
      },
    ],
});
this.#mapBuilderInstance.addTileLayerToMap(this.#mapInstance, geoTIFFSource);

addTileLayerToMap
addTileLayerToMap(map, source) {
    if (source) {
        const tileLayer = new TileLayerWebGL({
            source: source,
        });

        if (tileLayer) {
            map.addLayer(tileLayer);
            map.setView(source.getView().then((v) => {
                v.showFullExtent = false;
                return v;
            }));
        }            
    }
}

digit-area:

tiff-overlay

update:
the combination between parameters set to GeoTIFF instance and the solution of Mike, works fine, and yielded the following sample:
geoTIFFSource = new GeoTIFF({ wrapX: false, normalize: false, sources: [ { blob: res, overviews: ['openlayers.org/data/raster/no-overviews.tif.ovr'], }, ], }); 

updated overlay:

nodata:0


Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code of what has been tried so far, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

@TomazicM yes sure i will add it

@TomazicM code added, is that ok?

It looks like it is displaying a single band so it is black for no data regions.  Try adding  nodata: 0 or nodata: NaN to the source options to add an alpha band.

@Mike but why i can not zoom in or zoom out as if the zoom option is locked

@Amr .getView() returns constraining options.  If you would prefer no constraints just set the opening resolution and remove the unneeded options v.resolution = v.resolutions[v.zoom]; delete v.extent; delete v.resolutions; delete v.zoom;  return v;

@Mike thank you for your comment. Would you please provide what you mention as code?because it look a bit obscure to me. Sorry for any inconveniences

To remove extent and resolution constraints from the view you could use
        map.addLayer(tileLayer);
        map.setView(source.getView().then((v) => {
            v.resolution = v.resolutions[v.zoom];
            delete v.extent;
            delete v.resolutions;
            delete v.zoom; 
            return v;
        }));

To eliminate black in the output it might be easier to do that in your styling if you cannot get nodata to work, for example
      style: {
        color: [
          'case',
          ['>', ['band', 1], 0],
          [
            'array',
            ['band', 1],
            ['band', 1],
            ['band', 1],
            1,
          ],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
        ],
      },


Thank you, I will acknowledge once tested.

good morning, i have just tried the code you posted.unfortunately, when i run the code, there is not tiff overlays the feature or the geometry selected on the map. is there any solution for that please

the code you provided works with combination with the following parameters set to the instance of GeoTIFF:
geoTIFFSource = new GeoTIFF({
wrapX: false,
normalize: false,
sources: [
{
blob: res,
overviews: ['https://openlayers.org/data/raster/no-overviews.tif.ovr'],
},
],
});      please have a look at the update section added to the question

is there any way to eliminate the that part of the tiff in dark black color surrounds the feature/geometry

Have you tried sources: [ { blob: res, nodata: 0, .... ?

please have a look at the section title nodata:0 post above in the question. it shows the result when i set nodata:0

Also remove the overviews option, the one for the OpenLayers example is not relevant to your data

I removed the overviews options, but nothing changed in the results!

would you please have alook at this question?i created a new question for that issue:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/480597/how-to-eliminate-any-pixel-of-a-geotiff-that-does-not-intersect-with-the-geometr

I would not expect adding another band to change the grayscale output to white.  What is in your data?  Should the output match the color scale in your screenshots?

the tiff should contain ndvi values

It might be easier to eliminate invalid values when you style it, I added a basic example to the answer.

thanks, would you please explain a little bit the code?it is not clear to me. also i create a separate question for this problem:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/480597/eliminate-any-pixel-of-a-geotiff-that-does-not-intersect-with-the-geometry-featu

You new question is not the same - that would be like having a GeoTIFF of the world but only wanting to show it in Switzerland as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html

actually, i posted that new question as an attempt to further describe the problem i am facing with being unable to eliminate the black pixels. dont you think that it is,by any means, relevant?
